# make all outgoing links noindex for google

Tags: jquery, html, css, .htaccess, noindex

i have too much outgoing link on my website.
i want to make them all `no index` for google.
i dont want to write `rel="no index"` per link...

```
(< a href="..." rel="noindex, nofollow" >...< /a > )
```

can i create a `class` and write this with css?

and then

```
<div class="noindexlinks">
```

Is this possible? Or can I edit my htaccess for this?

[website](http://tanktroubleswf3.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not assign `html` attributes via `css`.

You can however accomplish what you are looking to do with an arbitrary `css` class and some `jQuery`.

- First, create an arbitrary class, like `no_follow_links`
- Assign this class to various `<a>` tags like, `<a class="no_follow_links" href="http://address.com">`
- Write your `jQuery` code, **[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/offo8gcv/)** using the [attr](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_attr.asp) method

**[`NOINDEX`](http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html)** is a meta tag, you're looking for [`nofollow`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nofollow) on your `<a>` tags.

```js
$(".no_follow_links").each(function(){
 $(this).attr("rel","nofollow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="no_follow_links" href="http://google.com">Link</a>
<a class="no_follow_links" href="http://bing.com">Link</a>
<a class="no_follow_links" href="http://yahoo.com">Link</a>
```